# Why getting exception 'Parameter is not valid'?

Tags: c#, winforms

a bit long code but the event and the method both connected to each other.

The selected index changed event of listbox:

```
private void listBoxCroppedImages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isRealTimeCropping)
    {
        var si = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
        if (si >= 0 && si < MyItems.Count)
        {
            var selectedItem = MyItems[si];

            // Check if the selected item is a free roam shape
            if (selectedItem.Message == "Free Roam Shape")
            {
                // Display the free roam shape
                DisplayFreeRoamShape();
            }
            else
            {
                // Display the rectangle
                var selectedKey = FileList.Keys.ElementAt(si); // Here we fetch the key at index si
                var selectedValue = FileList.Values.ElementAt(si);

                RichTextBoxController(si, selectedKey, selectedValue);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedKey) && FileList.ContainsKey(selectedKey))
                {
                    var filePath = FileList[selectedKey];
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        // Extract location and size from the selectedKey
                        Point location = ExtractLocation(selectedKey);
                        Size size = ExtractSize(selectedKey);

                        // Load the image
                        Image croppedImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);

                        // Create a new bitmap with a transparent background
                        Bitmap composedImage = new Bitmap(pictureBoxCroppedImages.Width, pictureBoxCroppedImages.Height);
                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(composedImage))
                        {
                            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);

                            // Draw the cropped image at the specified location and size
                            g.DrawImage(croppedImage, new Rectangle(location, size));
                        }

                        // Set the composed image to the pictureBoxCroppedImages
                        pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = composedImage;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var si = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
        if (si >= 0 && si < FileList.Count)
        {
            var selectedKey = FileList.Keys.ElementAt(si); // Here we fetch the key at index si
            var selectedValue = FileList.Values.ElementAt(si);

            RichTextBoxController(si, selectedKey, selectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```

When selecting a Free Roam Shape in the list box items then it's getting to the line

```
pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = composedImage;
```

I used a breakpoint and it does getting to the line and I see that composedImage is not null it's a bitmap type but then when making continue it's not even getting to the catch but right away getting to the Program.cs and throw the exception on this line

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

The error message

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Parameter is not valid.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
   at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The method to display

```
private void DisplayFreeRoamShape()
{
    var si = listBoxCroppedImages.SelectedIndex;

    if (si >= 0 && si < MyItems.Count)
    {
        var selectedItem = MyItems[si];

        if (selectedItem.Message == "Free Roam Shape")
        {
            try
            {
                // Load and display the corresponding free roam image
                if (FreeRoamShapes.Count > 0)
                {
                    var freeRoamShape = FreeRoamShapes[0]; // Assuming there is only one free roam shape
                    using (Bitmap composedImage = new Bitmap(pictureBoxCroppedImages.Width, pictureBoxCroppedImages.Height))
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(composedImage))
                    {
                        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                        using (Pen pen = new Pen(freeRoamShape.Color, 2f))
                        {
                            g.DrawPath(pen, freeRoamShape.Path);
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = composedImage;
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            // Handle any exceptions related to displaying the free roam shape
                            MessageBox.Show("Error displaying the free roam shape: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions related to displaying the free roam shape
                MessageBox.Show("Error displaying the free roam shape: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This exception is typically thrown **when you try to use a disposed `Graphics` object** which is passed to and used in other methods. Watch for your two `using (Graphics g = ...` lines. You may try removing these 2 `using` lines and dispose the `Graphics` objects in another appropriate place.

Comment: Make soure your `composedImage` has both width and height > 0. The error may also be thrown if you try to create a bitmap with size 0.

Comment: pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image = composedImage; is where the trouble started, composedImage is getting disposed a bit later by the *using* statement above it.  You have to keep it alive, at best you'd use `if (pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image != null) pictureBoxCroppedImages.Image.Dispose()` before the assignment to get rid of an old image.